# Datatables rowreorder moves only by one line

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am having a problem with jQuery Datatables, just added `rowReorder` option to my table, the problem is that when I drag and drop the selected row it moves only by one row. The option that I used was:

```
rowReorder: true,
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4gfh00u8/

Tried looking at the documentation or answers but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a column or data property with a sequence number. By default, RowReorder extension is looking for it in the first column.

In the [basic initialization example](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/simple.html), it says:

> The first column in the table is a sequence number that provides the basis for the ordering.

If you don't want to display sequence number in the table, you can also specify data source for sequence number with [`rowReorder.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowReorder.dataSrc).

There are couple other issues with your code, for example, ordering should not be disabled with `order: false`. Also there is a typo in `columnDefs` option name.

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/4gfh00u8/3/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is [rowReorder.update](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowReorder.update), as the docs say:

> By default RowReorder will [...] redraw the table to account for any changes in ordering.
>
> **This action is not always desirable, particularly if you are using
> server-side processing or wish to have an external process update the
> data**

So we can disable the update and handle the reordering event (storing the new ordering to db) with a custom function (with `table.on('row-reorder')`):

```
"rowReorder": {
    dataSrc: 5, // hidden column, it contains the object id
    update: false
},
```